# Download image to gallery in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to save / download image to galley in an Ionic2 application. But I could not save to gallery . Please correct me if there is any error in my code.

### Code1: Capturing Image

```
takeYourPicture(source) {
        if (source === 1) {
            this.camera.getPicture({
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                correctOrientation: true,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            }).then((imageData) => {
                this.base64Image = imageData;
                this.downloadLocation(this.base64Image);
            }, (error) => {

            })
        } else if (source === 0) {
            this.camera.getPicture({
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }).then((imageData) => {
                this.base64Image = imageData;
                this.downloadLocation(this.base64Image);
            }, (error) => {

            })
        }
    }
```

### Code2:Download Location

```
 downloadLocation(img) {
    let storageDirectory: string = "";
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        storageDirectory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
        console.log("Directory Ios=>"+storageDirectory);
    }
    else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        storageDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
        console.log("Directory Android=>"+storageDirectory);
    }
    else {
        // exit otherwise, but you could add further types here e.g. Windows
        return false;
    }
    this.downloadImage(storageDirectory,img);
}
```

### Code3: Download Image

```
downloadImage(storageDirectory, img) {
        const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        console.log("Base 64 0f Image:" + img);
        fileTransfer.download(img, storageDirectory + "sample.jpg").then((entry) => {
            const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: `Download Succeeded!`,
                subTitle: `Image was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alertSuccess.present();
        }, (error) => {
            const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: `Download Failed!`,
                subTitle: `Image was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alertFailure.present();
        });
    }
```

where `transfer` is added to constructor as `private transfer: Transfer`
NB : It may be duplicate of some other questions, please help me to solve this .

Thanks and Regards
Anand

Comment: The `saveToPhotoAlbum` property (set to `true`) should already save the picture in the gallery.

Comment: But I could not find the image on the device